# Angular 2: Route data is undefined on page refresh

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Data passed via route data attribute is undefined when the page is refreshed. I am using route protection and based on the privilegeId of the module, canActivate returns Observable boolean.

**home.routing.ts**

```
export const HomeRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
            {
                path: 'groups',
                loadChildren: 'app/modules/groups/groups.module#GroupsModule',
                data: { privilegeId: 5 }
            }
        ]
    },
];
export const HomeRouting = RouterModule.forChild(HomeRoutes);
```

**auth-guard.service.ts**

```
canActivate(routeSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
// Issue: privilegeId is undefined on page reload.
let privilegeId = routeSnapshot.data["privilegeId"] as number;

// Calls API with privilege id and returns boolean.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you can't access the route data in a parents guard after refreshing.

First of all the best way to protect your children routes is by using `canActivateChild` instead of `canActivate`.

Now weirdly only after a refresh, the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` is not in the scope of the current route, which means the current route does not have the route data.

Fortunately the complete route is contained in the `RouterStateSnapshot` within the `root`-Property which is a tree.

You can now walk down this tree (containing only one child each) and look if one of the children has any data:

```typescript
searchData(state: RouterStateSnapshot, dataKey: string): string | null {
    if (state.root.data && state.root.data[dataKey])
        return state.root.data[dataKey];
    let child: ActivatedRouteSnapshot | null;
    child = state.root.firstChild;
    while (child != null) {
        if (child.data && child.data[dataKey]) {
            return child.data[dataKey];
        }
        child = child.firstChild;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This method searches the `RouterStateSnapshot` for data with a specified key and returns either the first occurence (if any) or null